# Python - creating a delay that takes in account the execution time

Tags: python, image-processing, time, delay

i am writing a function that reads N (800*600) frames from a bin file in one sec. the FPS is user controllable

```
import time

def getFrame(file,N):  #read N frames per second, 800X600 pixels each from file
    start = time.time()
    delay = (1/float(N))
    while N:
        frame = file.read(480000)
        time.sleep(delay)
        N -= 1
    print time.time()-start
    return
```

the time.sleep() creates the delay, but without taking in account the execution time of the rest of the code.
so in total the running time is always bigger then 1 sec and it increments as i increase my N (fps) value.

is there a way to create a delay that takes into account the processing time ?

Comment: here's [code example that writes with constant bit-rate](https://gist.github.com/zed/9cb41b2cfe615a7be3e9). `pygame` has [`tick()` method (look at how it is implemented)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ummm .... you need basic math here

```
time.sleep(delay-(time.time()-start))
```